# How do I fix a rejected git fetch to a bare repository?

Tags: git, git-fetch

I'm the author of WorldPainter (a map generator for Minecraft). I have a set of git repositories set up to be able to work on WorldPainter at home and at work. There is a full repository on my workstation at home ([Home]) and one at work ([Work]). To transfer changes between them I have set up a bare repository on a network share at home ([Net]) and another bare repository on a USB stick ([USB]). [Home] and [USB] have [Net] as a remote repository, and [Work] has [USB] as a remote repository.

In addition, but I think it is probably not relevant, [Net] has GitHub as a remote repository.

When I want to transfer changes from home to work I do:

[Home] -push-> [Net] <-fetch- [USB] <-pull- [Work]

To transfer changes the other way:

[Work] -push-> [USB] -push-> [Net] <-pull- [Home]

This has worked great so far, but today the fetch from [Net] to [USB] went wrong with the following message:

```
remote: Counting objects: 13, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Total 13 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (13/13), done.
From file:///mnt/git-repos/WorldPainter-public
 ! [rejected]        master     -> master  (non-fast-forward)
```

A push from [USB] to [Net] now fails with a similar message.

I'm finding git very complex and counter-intuitive and at this point I'm lost. If I understand the situation correctly this most likely means that there are conflicting changes which need merging, but since [USB] is a bare repository, I can't merge them.

I've probably done some things in the wrong order to get in this situation, but how do I fix it? Is there a way to temporarily add a working directory to [USB] so I can merge the changes there? Can I move the problem to one of the repositories which *does* have a working directory and fix the problem there? I'm aware that I can --force the fetch, but that's not very elegant and would probably result in losing changes, right?

Comment: As I understand [USB] contain code which you not push to the [NET], also [Work] contain this code too?

Comment: @axon No, both [Net] and [USB] contain all my changes. I use them to transfer all my changes between workstations at home, to and from work, and to GitHub.

Comment: yeah, I get it!
I mean in the current situation, you wrote that you done some things in wrong order. So I guess your [Work] and [Usb] contain one of version of your code, but [Home] and [Net] the other version. Is it correct?
If yes you can try do `git push --force` from [USB] to [Net], and after it `git pull` from [Net] to [Home], fix conflicts, and in the end doin `git push` from [Home] to [Net]. Hope you understand me :)

Comment: @axon Ah, sorry! Yes, that appears to be the case. I tried to transfer some changes from work to home and from home to work simultaneously, which was foolish. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll see if I can fix it that way.